# If found a broken link on bitcoin.org - who manages the site?

Tags: bitcoin.org

just a minor issue but yet:

MIT license link has moved from this:
https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

to this:
https://opensource.org/licenses/mit

Source page with the broken link:
https://bitcoin.org/en/download

Thanks!
Yosi

Answer (score 2):

You can make a pull request on their official Github regarding line 400 and 963 from this file: https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/blob/master/_translations/en.yml

Line 400

> notelicense: "Bitcoin Core is a community-driven https://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software\">free
>   software project, released under the http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php\">MIT
>   license."

Line 963

> footer: "Released under the http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php\"
>   target=\"_blank\">MIT license"

Don't forget [other translations](https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/tree/master/_translations) as well ! :)

Otherwise, if your are not confortable with Git you can just open [a new issue](https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues).